# Cada vez que quiero hacer push a Bitbucket me pide mi usuario y contraseña, ¿Cómo puedo evitar esto?

Tags: bitbucket

Cada vez que quiero hacer push a `Bitbucket` me abre una ventana donde me pide ingresar mi usuario y contraseña de `Bitbucket`, es molesto estar haciendo esto a cada rato, ¿Cómo poder quitarlo?

Comment: Puedes configurar tu `clave SSH` siguiendo [esta guía](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html)

Answer (score 1):

Mediante `git config credentials` puedes cachear tu usuario y contraseña. Por defecto lo guarda por 15 minutos, pero puedes pasarle como argumento la cantidad en segundos. Por ejemplo, para guardar tus credenciales por 4 horas:

```
git config credential.helper "cache timeout=14400"
```

Si usas Windows se debe usar el módulo `wincred`:

```
git config credential.helper wincred "cache timeout=14400"
```

Para MacOS, la documentación sugiere que uses el keystore nativo (osxkeychain):

```
git config credential.helper osxkeychain "cache timeout=14400"
```

Comment: Genial, gracias, y esto solo pasa en bitbucket? porque estoy trabajando en otro proyecto que se encuentra alojado en gitlab y nunca me habia pasado esto.

Comment: Bitbucket, Gitlab o GitHub, todos usan Git que es el software de control de versión, por lo tanto es universal.

Comment: Aún me sigue apareciendo, me aparece esto:

Comment: git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
error: unable to read askpass response from 'C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass'

Comment: Cuando instalaste git, marcaste las opciones para habilitar caching y credentials manager?

Comment: No lo sé, quizá no me percaté de esa opción

Answer (score 0):

En windows: Con ésta herramienta http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/106064

En linux:

```html
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 3600'   
git help credential-cache
```

En Osx:

```html
chmod a+x git-credential-osxkeychain                                                                                  
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

Answer (score 0):

Tambien puedes añadir tu propia ssh-key en bitbucket, y asi cada vez que utilices push, no te pide contraseña.

Dejo esto como solución, para que veas que en el propio bitbucket tienes un manual para solucionarlo, pero realmente te hago referencia al manual para la proxima vez no tener que buscar.

Vete al navegador y accede a bitbucket; en tu perfil, en la opcion de settings, tienes un apartado SECURITY, y el primer enlace es "ssh-keys". Pulsa en el.

fijate en el texto `Use SSH to avoid password prompts when you push code to Bitbucket. Learn how to generate an SSH key.`

Ahi veras un enlace que te explica como generar un ssh key, segun tu S.O. Siguiendo ese manual (añadiendo tu ssh-key en bitbucket) veras que luego no te pide user:pass al hacer push.

Answer (score 0):

En la [documentacion de git](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Herramientas-de-Git-Almacenamiento-de-credenciales) se describe las diferentes opciones que tienes:

Usar ssh-key es la mejor opcion, pero debes **tener cuidado** con las claves que se almacenan en tu computadora, ademas de retirarlas y llevartelas si piensas cambiar de computadora alguna vez.

Por otro lado, si no quieres introducir ningun tipo de credencial, debes configurar una ssh-key sin **secret-phrase**, si no, te la pedira cuando uses este protocolo y tendras el mismo problema.